# Make a textbox's name match a dynamically generated select box's value

Tags: javascript, forms

I need to POST a form to a CMS and that CMS has specific fields for Alimony, Child Support, Insurance, etc.  My problem is that in my form, not all of these boxes exist until the user adds it or selects it from the dropdown.

At first there is a select box named "selectBox" that has all of these options inside of it.  If the user selects "Alimony" I want the name of the corresponding textbox the change to "payment_alimony" so when I make the POST, the fields match up to the CMS.

Next, if the user needs to add another expense, he will click "Add an Expense" and a select box pops up named "selectBox2" and so on up to 10.

I would prefer to be able to do this without having to have 10 separate functions for each selectBox if possible.

Thank you for your assistance!

```
<div id="income1" class="row clonedInput"><!-- Expandable Section: INCOME -->
                                <div class="item" id="item_income_source">
                                    <label for="income_source">Additional Income Source<a href="javascript:;" class="tooltip" title="Help Text Goes Here"></a></label>
                                    <select id="income_source" name="income_source"   >
                                        <option value="" selected="selected">- select -</option>
                                        <option value="alimony">Alimony</option>
                                        <option value="child_support">Child Support</option>
                                        <option value="disability">Disability</option>
                                        <option value="social_security">Social Security</option>
                                        <option value="pension">Pension</option>
                                        <option value="rental_protperty">Rental Property</option>
                                        <option value="other">Other</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item small-item third ">
                                    <label for="blank-space">&nbsp;</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item small-item third last" id="item_input_gross">
                                    <label for="input_gross">Amount ($)</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="input_gross" value="" name="input_gross" onkeyup="formatInt(this)" onChange="addIncome();" onclick="select();" class="IncometoAdd"  />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="clear:both">
                                <input type="button" id="btnAdd-Income" value="(+) add source" />
                                <input type="button" id="btnDel-Income" value="(-) remove source" />
                            </div>
```

And the Javascript that duplicates:

```
$(function(){
// Add new element
$('#btnAdd-Income').click(function() {
    var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
    var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

    // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
    var newElem = $('#income' + num).clone().attr('id', 'income' + newNum);

    // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
    newElem.find('#item_income_source label').attr('for', 'income_source' + newNum);
    newElem.find('#item_income_source select').attr('id', 'income_source' + newNum).attr('name', 'income_source' + newNum).val('');
    newElem.find('#item_input_gross label').attr('for', 'input_gross' + newNum);
    newElem.find('#item_input_gross input').attr('id', 'input_gross' + newNum).attr('name', 'input_gross' + newNum).val('');

    // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
    $('#income' + num).after(newElem);

    // enable the "remove" button
    $('#btnDel-Income').show();

    // Limit 6 sources  ***EDITABLE***
    if (newNum == 6)
        $('#btnAdd-Income').hide();
});

    // remove the last element
$('#btnDel-Income').click(function() {
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    $('#income' + num).remove();        // remove the last element
    addIncome();

    // enable the "add" button
    $('#btnAdd-Income').show();

    // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
    if (num-1 == 1)
        $('#btnDel-Income').hide();
});

$('#btnDel-Income').hide();
```

});

Comment: Where's your existing code? What have you tried?

Comment: Is a jQuery solution OK?

Comment: Can you at least show the basic structure of your form, so we know where to start from?

Comment: See how quick you get good answers when you provide a complete question? :)

Comment: This forum is amazing.  I have never needed to post until today, usually everything is so easy to find on here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
$(function() {
  $('#btnAdd-Income').click(function() {
      source = $('.item').first().clone();
      source.find('input').val('');
      $('.item').last().after(source);
  });

  $('.item select').live('change', function() {
      name = $('option:selected',this).val();
     $('input.amount', $(this).closest('.item')).attr('name', name); 
  });
});​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item" id="item_income_source">
    <label for="income_source">Additional Income Source<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="Help Text Goes Here"></a></label>
    <select id="income_source" name="income_source"   >
     <option value="" selected="selected">- select -</option>
     <option value="alimony">Alimony</option>
     <option value="child_support">Child Support</option>
     <option value="disability">Disability</option>
     <option value="social_security">Social Security</option>
     <option value="pension">Pension</option>
     <option value="rental_protperty">Rental Property</option>
     <option value="other">Other</option>
   </select>

  <label for="input_gross">Amount ($)</label>
  <input type="text" id="input_gross" class="amount"    />
 <br>
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both">
 <input type="button" id="btnAdd-Income" value="(+) add source" />
 <input type="button" id="btnDel-Income" value="(-) remove source" />
</div>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ft6ME/32/

Comment: i wrote my fiddle based on your initial question so this should be close to what you are looking for. play around with the fiddle for a bit and let me know if its close to what you need.

Comment: see updated. if you want the select boxes to be named 'selectBox' incrementally, let me know, but i do not see how that would serve a purpose.

Comment: Good moorning! Thanks for the post. I am not sure what you mean about making it intuitive without cloning the select box. My code clones the entire row so I think at this point I need to figure out how to get the name of the text box to match the value of the select box on the same row.

Comment: ah, okay. thats exactly what my code does. take a look at the fiddle link and inspect the text box. you can see the name change as you choose another selection in the select list.

Comment: Amazing Cooper! Quick question, why does the value of the text box duplicate in this example?  For example if I add the first value of 500 and then I add a new expense, the default value is 500.

Comment: this is because .clone() makes a clone of the element selected, which currently is the 1st .item. I added an extra line of code to make sure we clear the input value. see the updated fiddle link.

Comment: The reason I am incrementing the select boxes is primarily so the hover on the label matches the right box :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right, this is all you need:

```
<select onChange="this.name = 'payment_'+this.value">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="alimony">Alimony</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry, I dropped the ball on this one.  The text box name needs to change :(

Comment: Just change `this.name` to whatever you want to affect.

Comment: The text box changes name as it increments, is there a way to target it dynamically?